# openstack rest API start/stop server

Tags: php, openstack

I have created server via the web UI of my hosting provider. 
I want to be able to stop (shutdown) and start this server on demand from another server via their Openstack API.

I am using [php-opencloud/openstack](https://github.com/php-opencloud/openstack). I can get server by:

```
 $compute = $openstack->computeV2(['region' => $region]);
 $server = $compute->getServer(['id' => $server_id]);
 $server->retrieve();
```

then I can reboot via:

```
$server->reboot();
```

but how can I just stop the server and then start it ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this functionality is not implemented yet, but I found a solution here: https://github.com/php-opencloud/openstack/pull/75/files

The API documentation about this can be found here:
http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2.1.html#os-server-actions-v2.1

Basically you have to send "os-start" and "os-stop", the code in github shows how.